# ffprobe or avprobe returning plain text errors in JSON output

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe, avconv, avprobe

I'm running `avprobe` to get stream infomation about a video in `JSON` ...

`avprobe -loglevel quiet -show_format -show_streams file.m4v -of json`

This is basically the exact same thing as `ffprobe` or `ffmpeg -i` (and I get the same error.)

`ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_format -show_streams file.m4v -print_format json`

The command works most of the time ... however, on occation I'll have a video that has an odd stream in it that is "unsupported" and I'll get back something like this (abbreviated.)

```
Unsupported codec with id 94213 for input stream 2
{  "format" : {
    "filename" : "file.m4v",
    "nb_streams" : 3,
    "format_name" : "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2" ...
```

When I run the command I get back `JSON` + an error in `plain text`, which makes the result invalid `JSON` and I have to "clean it up" later.

I'm **suppressing errors** from the output `-loglevel quiet` but the error still show up.

How can I tell `avprobe/ffprobe` to not show this error and hence get back a proper `JSON` object?

---

### Longer Output Examples

### `ffprobe`, from source, MacOS

```
ffprobe version 0.9.1-subsplash, Copyright (c) 2007-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  5 2012 01:35:36 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --as=yasm --extra-version=subsplash --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree
  libavutil    51. 32. 0 / 51. 32. 0
  libavcodec   53. 42. 4 / 53. 42. 4
  libavformat  53. 24. 2 / 53. 24. 2
  libavdevice  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavfilter   2. 53. 0 /  2. 53. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2012-01-01 06:38:43
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.5 2011010300
  Duration: 00:30:47.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1558 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start -0.066733, end 17.784433
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter  1

...

    Stream #0:2(und): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-01-01 06:38:43
      handler_name    : 
Unsupported codec with id 94213 for input stream 2
{

...
```

### `avprobe`, from source, Ubuntu Linux

```
avprobe version 10_alpha1-6:10~~git20130307.4be368b-1~quantal1, Copyright (c) 2007-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar  7 2013 22:12:44 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2012-01-01 06:38:43
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.5 2011010300
  Duration: 00:30:47.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1558 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start -0.066733, end 17.784433
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter  1

...

    Stream #0.2(und): Subtitle: text / 0x74786574
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-01-01 06:38:43
Unsupported codec with id 94213 for input stream 2
{

...
```

Comment: Options go before the input file although it will not make a difference in your case. Please show the complete `ffprobe` console output without `-loglevel quiet` of a file that gives the `Unsupported codec` message.

Comment: The "full" output is *exactly* the same as a file not having this "problem" ... the only difference is that between the `Metadata:` section and the `JSON` (shown in the post) the error `Unsupported codec with id 94213 for input stream 2` is thrown even though I suppressed errors.

Comment: I'm more interested in the version information which should be present in the full output.

Comment: Please confirm that using a recent build works as expected. Static builds for Linux, OS X, and Windows are available via links on the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page. Use the most recent build available. Or compile from Git head if you prefer [[Ubuntu compile guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide)].

Comment: I encountered the same issue with binaries built from the `git` source ...

Comment: I can't duplicate the issue, even with a sample that would usually give such a message in `ffmpeg`. Perhaps you can provide one.

Comment: The title has a typo: command should be "avprobe" NOT "avprove". Fix that you may expose your question to more people to answer it :)

Comment: So @JustinJenkins did you find the solution? Apparently 2 years later I am having same problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590234/ffmpeg-pushed-rtmp-stream-not-working-on-android-iphone

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is both the output of STDOUT and STDERR.  If you want to filter out the `Unsupported codec with id 94213 for input stream 2`, you could for example filter out the STDERR output by redirecting it to /dev/null like this in bash:

`avprobe -loglevel quiet -show_format -show_streams file.m4v -of json 2>/dev/null`