# FFMPEG pushed RTMP stream not working on Android & iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I have to make a semi-live-stream. I used Nginx-rtmp module and then pushed content to it via ffmpeg using:

```
ffmpeg -re -i content.mp4 -r 25 -f fvl "rtmp://rtmp.server.here"
```

The stream runs fine when I open it in VLC from "rtmp://rtmp.server.here"

But I also have to make iPhone and Android apps that play these streams. *And that's the problem,* the stream doesn't work on Android and iPhone.

If I use Wowza streaming cloud and stream to Wowza cloud instead of my own nginx-rtmp server then the same app written for Android & iPhone can playback the stream just fine.

Now either nginx-rtmp is not working right, or what else? I've also tried crtmpserver and the same thing happens.

**What I want to acheive:**
I have to develop a system where we can upstream a TV-Channel (have rights for it) to a server and then make a website, android app & iPhone app so consumers can watch the live channel.

The uploading part I have a clue of, probably a TV tuner card and Open Broadcast Software to stream it to server. But the Live playback is new to me.

---

**UPDATE:** I also used ffprobe and here's the output. (See the last line)

```
munir@munir-HP-ProBook-450-G2:~$ ffprobe rtmp://rtmp.server.here
ffprobe version 2.6.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[flv @ 0x267cc60] Stream discovered after head already parsed
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://stage.funworldpk.com/live':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 320
    displayHeight   : 240
    fps             : 20
    profile         : 
    level           : 
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 288.763000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 20 fps, 20 tbr, 1k tbn, 40 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 1
```

**Update 2:**
I got my stream working by using Licensed copy of Wowza streaming server. Everything works now. But obviously this will not be an option for everyone that's why I am not posting it as an answer.

Comment: You could try to use `ffprobe` to check if there are encoding differences between your stream and the Wowza output.

Comment: @aergistal I've update the answer with ffprobe output.

Comment: Compare `ffprobe` output for Wowza and Nginx streams

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Anatoly I think I did. The solution was to move away from unstable/buggy open-source solutions in this case. And use Wowza streaming server licence for $60 a month :|

Answer (score 2):

RTMP protocol usage is very limited and primarily being used for video recording. There is no reason to use it for playback as mobile devices don't support RTMP natively, you don't think it can be a good idea to advice mobile users to install VLC or similar app on the device?

Plugin [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) has been incorporated to Nginx+ to make a comprehensive recording media server out of Nginx as a replacement to Wowza Media Server or implement HLS for playaback via HTTP. This plugin can be used with Nginx open source edition.

To make your video content available to mobile devices you have only 2 options, each of them work via HTTP(s), not RTMP:

1. [HTTP Live Streaming](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_hls_module.html), see the example:

   ```
   location / {
       hls;
       hls_fragment            5s;
       hls_buffers             10 10m;
       hls_mp4_buffer_size     1m;
       hls_mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
       root /var/video/;
   }
   ```
2. [HTTP pseudo streaming](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html), see the example

   ```
   location /video/ {
       mp4;
       mp4_buffer_size       1m;
       mp4_max_buffer_size   5m;
       mp4_limit_rate        on;
       mp4_limit_rate_after  30s;
   }
   ```

   The other side is security. How to protect the video streaming URL? Pre-generated time-expired URLs is good approach, you can try, see my example [there](https://gist.github.com/mikhailov/3174601).

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry for late reply. I was really busy with other top priority work at my company earlier.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your input video uses `H.264` with a `high` profile.

   If you want compatibility with **both iOS and Android** you **must** use the `baseline` profile. [Newer iPhones](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) support the `main` and `high` profiles but the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) only mentions `baseline`:

   `-c:v libx264 -profile baseline`
2. Don't use the native `aac` as audio codec, use `libfdk_aac` since it's the highest quality encoder available for FFmpeg and it will help you produce a valid AAC stream:

   `-c:a libfdk_aac`
3. Make sure the audio rate is suported. The `FLV` video format only supports sample rates of 11025, 22050, and 44100.

   `-ar 44100`
4. The `ffprobe` shows an unsupported stream `Stream #0:1: Data: none`. Use `map` to skip it:

   `-map 0:0 -map 0:2`
5. (MPEG-TS only) If you use a `.ts` file as input make sure to remove the AAC ADTS header:

   `-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc`

Eg:

```
ffmpeg -re -i content.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -c:v libx264 -vprofile baseline -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you add more details about the file (`ffprobe`) so it could be compared with the server output.
Alternatively, be more strict in your `ffmpeg` command and set a specific output.
That's a command I use to push RTMP to YouTube:
`ffmpeg -i any_file.mp4 -strict experimental -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 30 -vb 512k -profile:v main -preset ultrafast -r 30 -f flv -s 854x480 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/your-channel.stream_code`

With you last update, there already is a difference between `ffmpeg` output and the server's: `ffmpeg` creates a 25fps stream while `ffprobe` sees a 20fps stream.
Is there a place in the server you set other output parameters? try setting the `ffmpeg` output accordingly.

See if changing the `ffmpeg` output affects the server output, and try go with h264 main profile.

Regarding the `ffprobe` error message, if your original file also contains 3 streams, perhaps the server doesn't like it so remove that 'Data' stream using `map` like this:
`ffmpeg -i content.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:2 ...`

Comment: While the `main` and `high` profiles are supported on newer iPhones, the Android documentation only mentions the `baseline` profile for H.264 AVC so you have to go with that instead if you need compatibility with both platforms. The default `aac` encoder is **NOT** recommended (hint: the `-strict-experimental` part). The best option for valid AAC output is `libfdk_aac`